# how to make mini_magick ruby gem put russian characters on image?

Tags: ruby, image

Вместо русских букв выводит \u1234\u5678 а хотелось бы русские подписи на картинки ставить
    require 'mini_magick'

```
text = "Hel1o! Привет"
img = MiniMagick::Image.open("jpeg.jpg")
sign = MiniMagick::Image.open("im999.png")

puts text

img.combine_options do |c|
  c.draw "text 0,75 '#{text}'"
  c.encoding "UTF-8"
  c.gravity 'North'
  c.pointsize '22'
  c.font 'Tahoma'
  c.fill("#000000")
end
#img.write "new.jpg"

res =img.composite sign do |c|
  c.gravity "South"
end
res.write("new.jpg")
```

Comment: Would you mind to notice this site uses English as the language to ask questions.

Comment: Try to `draw` after the settings are applied (e.g. put `c.draw "text 0,75 '#{text}'"` just before `end`. This should help.

Comment: @mudasobwa, thx for answer, i tried that variant - its not working. also i tried different fonts and couple other gems(working in windows)

Comment: What’s the default encoding at your target OS? Would you show the output of `locale` command?

Comment: @mudasobwa, there is no such command in windows

Comment: Your **target** OS is windows? I’m putting my hands in my pockets.